# How to compare Array List with List Web Elements in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have an `ArrayList` and a `WebElement` list with same data.  I need to know how I can compare the values in my `ArrayList` with values in my List `WebElements`:

```
ArrayList<String> shift = new ArrayList<String>();
shift.add("A1");
shift.add("A2");
shift.add("A3");
shift.add("B1");
shift.add("B2");
shift.add("B3");

System.out.println("List of all elements: " + shift);

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By
                           .className("shift-names"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If lists should be fully same, then you can do next:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= elements.count(); i++) {
    String textActual = elements[i].getText();
    String textExpected = shift.get(i);
    Assert.areEquals(textActual, textExpected);
}
```

Maybe a problem with syntax.